# How to group by mysql to fill empty row

Tags: mysql

I have this records

```
ID Name  key1   key2 key 3
1   A    Key1A   Key2A Key3A 
2   B    Key1B   NULL NULL
3   B    NULL   Key2B Ke3yB
4   C    Key1C   NULL  NULL
5   C    NULL   Key2C  NULL
6   C    NULL   NULL  Key3C
```

So i need result like this

```
 Name  key1     key2  key 3
  A    Key1A   Key2A  Key3A 
  B    Key1B   Key2B  Key3B
  C    Key1C   Key2C  Key3C
```

Is it possible to achieve it  ? thanks in advance

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen my bad, it was wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregate by name and take the max of each other column:

```
SELECT
    Name,
    MAX(key1) AS key1,
    MAX(key2) AS key2,
    MAX(key3) AS key3
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    Name;
```

This works because the `MAX` function, when used to aggregate, ignores `NULL` values.  So, if a given column has a number of records only one of which is not `NULL`, that value would be retained after aggregating.

Comment: I never thought about it. I almost create a temprory table and use the loop update things . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sharing my ideas on this, you can use `group_concat`and if there are duplicate values `distinct` will give a result in unique.

```
SELECT 
    `Name`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT key1),
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT key2),
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT key3)
FROM
    your_table
GROUP BY `Name`;
```

**Note:** If you have multiple value for a `Name` in a single`key(n)` column then it will result more than one value for that column.